# I can't add multiple text clicking by add button & showing some extra CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My first problem is that when I'm taking text from an input field and a div, the input field text is okay but the div text is showing extra CSS styling. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

```
<input id="accordion_input" type="text">
<div id="editableDiv"  contenteditable=""></div>
```

The second problem is when I click the 'Add' button then the input and div text is appearing only one time. I want to add the text multiple times by clicking the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Add_btn').click(function() {
    $('#accordion_body').text($('#editableDiv').html());
    var x = document.getElementById("accordion_input").value;
    document.getElementById("accordion_title").innerHTML = x;
  });  
  
  $("#acc_main").append(); 
});
```

```html
<input id="accordion_input" type="text">
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable=""></div>
<div id="acc_main" contenteditable="false" class="accordion-main">
  <div class="panel-group trash_removed" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" contenteditable="false">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a id="accordion_title"></a>
        </h4>
        <div id="expandingCol" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div id="accordion_body" class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myAccorFunction()" id="Add_btn">Add</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that you have an `onclick` attribute referencing a function which doesn't exist which is causing an error. Remove that attribute. They shouldn't be used anyway.

Regarding the 'CSS styling' you refer to, this is due to the encoded HTML which is visible as you're attempting to add HTML to an element using the `text()` method. Technically you should use `html()` instead, but given that you want to add a new instance of the strings on each button click, use `append()` instead. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Add_btn').click(function() {
    $('#accordion_body').append($('#editableDiv').html());
    
    var x = $("#accordion_input").val();
    $("#accordion_title").append(x);
  });  
});
```

```html
<input id="accordion_input" type="text">
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable=""></div>
<div id="acc_main" contenteditable="false" class="accordion-main">
  <div class="panel-group trash_removed" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" contenteditable="false">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a id="accordion_title"></a>
        </h4>
        <div id="expandingCol" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div id="accordion_body" class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="Add_btn">Add</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that I converted the native JS to jQuery; if you've loaded it you may as well use it. I also removed the `$("#acc_main").append();` line as it is useless code which does nothing at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Sir, As i said, i would like to multiple by ADD button here DIV Text is okay but the INPUT text  are showing one time! Sir can you please solve the issues?

Comment: Then just change `html()` there to `append()` as well. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)